# Convergence Issues in a Simple 5x5 Grid DQN-based Mini-game

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am a master's student studying reinforcement learning.

I am trying to build up my understanding of reinforcement learning concepts step by step in order to apply it to complex games.

I created a simple mini-game to apply the DQN method.

In a 5x5 grid game board, there are bombs (X), a destination (R), and a player (O).

The position of all objects is randomly placed at the beginning of each episode.
There are a total of 5 bombs.

Since it is a simple game, I was able to quickly proceed with the learning.

Like this :

```
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   | X | 
|---|---|---|---|---|
| X | X |   |   | X | 
|---|---|---|---|---|
| X |   |   |   |   | 
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   |   |   | O | 
|---|---|---|---|---|
|   |   | R |   |   | 
|---|---|---|---|---|
```

The player has four possible actions: up, down, left, and right.

- Moving to a normal cell gives a reward of -1.
- Moving to a bomb cell gives a reward of -10.
- Reaching the destination gives a reward of +100.

The current simple neural network configuration is as follows:
We use a Flatten input for the 5x5 game board data.

Neural Network:

```py
class FCModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_actions, width, height):
        super(FCModel, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = width * height
        self.fc_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(self.input_size, 512),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(512, 256),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(256, num_actions),
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view((-1, self.input_size))
        x = self.fc_layer(x)
        return x
```

Based on the results of the experiment with 1000 episodes,

it didn't converge as I wanted, and I observed convergence through a fixed placement rather than random placement.

However, even in a fixed placement, it was possible to see that it didn't converge, and I judged it as a problem with 'Experience Replay'.

By removing ER and updating at every step, I was able to see convergence in the fixed placement.

The simple hyperparameters used are as follows:

```py
lr = 0.001 # Use Adam Optimizer
gamma = 0.8
batch_size = 10
```

```py
def learn(self):
    if len(self.memories) < self.batch_size:
        return
    batch = random.sample(self.memories, self.batch_size)
    states, next_states, actions, rewards = zip(*batch)
    states = torch.cat(states)
    next_states = torch.cat(next_states)
    actions = torch.cat(actions)
    rewards = torch.cat(rewards)

    q_values = self.model(states)
    current_q = q_values.gather(1, actions.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    next_max_q = self.model(next_states).gather(1, torch.max(q_values, 1)[1].unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    expected_q = rewards + (self.gamma * next_max_q)

    loss = F.mse_loss(current_q, expected_q)

    self.optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    self.optimizer.step()
```

1. In a game of this structure, does ER actually hinder convergence?
2. Is the lack of sufficient training the cause?
3. Or is there a problem with the code implementation?

If there are any issues with my implementation, please point them out.